# Is there any way to add a description at table level in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Suppose I have multiple tables in my database having almost similar name, so in that case, is it possible to add description at table level so, when i leave my current organization, it helps other developers to understand the use of table by it description. Just like we have it in Procedures

/*==============================================

Created By   : Someone

Description  : To Fetch Employee Details

Created Date : 2019-12-23 16:35:55.340

==============================================*/

Comment: Extended properties do exist, but personally (from experience), I feel good company documentation is a better place for such information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use extended properties for this, which is a feature in MS SQL Server that can be used for documentation purposes.

Here's example code on how to add a description for the Adress table in the Person schema in the AdventureWorks2012 database according to the MS documentation:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;  
GO  
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty   
@name = N'MS_DescriptionExample',   
@value = N'Street address information for customers, employees, and vendors.',   
@level0type = N'SCHEMA', @level0name = 'Person',  
@level1type = N'TABLE',  @level1name = 'Address';  
GO
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addextendedproperty-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: The answer you actually have deleted is, ironically, better as it has a link to the documentation. I realise, however, that you can't undelete it due to it being deleted by a moderator. I would suggest putting the link in this one too, but this does get my upvote.

Comment: I have added the link

Comment: Lets just repeat the comment a moderator deleted: In 30 years in IT focusing on SQL Server I have NEVER seen this used in practice. So, it wil lbe ignored. The best i found it in use is the sql sync in devart entity developer which can pull documentation fields from there.